# Shipping line items not displaying with [commerce-order:line-items]

Tags: views, tokens, commerce

I have Commerce and Shipping and Flat Rate installed and working correctly. Shipping is added to an Order and charged to the customer.

But when I go to display the shipping line items, e.g. in a order receipt email, they are missing.

My Rule uses this:

```
Order Details:
[commerce-order:commerce_line_items]

Total Price: [commerce-order:commerce_order_total]
```

This correctly displays each product line item, and the order total, including shipping line items, but does not display the shipping line items.

I read about a filter in the View at `admin/structure/views/view/commerce_line_item_table/edit/default` and I see that it is set to only display product line items. But I don't want to mess with that View unless I know what I am doing.

Can I Add a new View display? If so, which kind (Data export?) How to call that display in my Rule?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you enable the Token module (maybe you already have?), you are given a new view mode on all fieldable entity types called *Tokens*. You need to enable this in the *Custom display settings* fieldset on the *Manage display* page for order types (found under **Administration > Store > Configuration > Order settings**). Once you've done this, you'll be able to choose any eligible View you want for rendering the line item field's tokens, so if you add another display to the default View and remove that line item type filter, you can use that just for rendering the token.

You can read more w/ screenshots here: https://www.drupal.org/node/1299662

Comment: Thanks Ryan, I get it, but what type of display should I select when adding the display to the view?

Comment: Well, I just tried a few, Block seemed to be the one. It certainly worked and I got the shipping line items in the [commerce-order:commerce_line_items] token, as I expected. That was some deep juju to accomplish what would seem to be a very common task, though ... Or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Common task it may be, but it's not immediately obvious how it should be improved. I don't know a more explicit way given the current Field UI / Token constraints to choose different display formatters for a field based token. : )

Comment: Ryan, can I ask what is the rationale behind not including all line item types by default? Also, if I wrote up a little tutorial on this, where should I put it?

Comment: The View you're using is used just to show the cart contents, so we filter out non-product line items. The shipping total then appears in the footer of the View alongside taxes where the order total price components are displayed. We could've used multiple Views to accomplish a better behavior, but we also don't have the Shipping module in core and altering Views is unreliable (since it may have been customized in the UI prior to installing Shipping). A tutorial would be great! Do you have a blog? If not, use a child page in the Shipping 2.x documentation: https://www.drupal.org/node/1296716

Comment: OK. Tutorial published on my blog at http://websitebackendsolutions.com/blog/how-display-all-drupal-commerce-line-items-using-token . I will also update the Shipping doc page. Thanks Ryan!